# Is there any way to extend the durability of my DIY tools?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Sometimes it'd be nice to not have to worry about having enough resources to bring with me onto Mystery Islands, and to that I ask if there is any way to extend the durability of my DIY tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Upgrading your tools** seems to reset the durability of them.  For example, if I catch 7 fish with the Flimsy Fishing Rod, and upgrade it into a Fishing Rod, the durability is reset to that of whatever the Fishing Rod's durability is.

**Customizing your tools** also seems to be an easy way to reset the durability -- it seems that just purchasing a Customization Kit from Timmy and Tommy for 600 bells allows you to reset the durability of any of your tools at any time, and it's a lot more convenient carrying these around instead of hoarding wood and iron nuggets.